# Manipulating Salesforce html elements with Autohotkey via COM

Tags: html, autohotkey, javascript

I wrote an Autohotkey script that uses COM to automate updating Salesforce opportunities. At some point, the functionality broke. Previously, I could use javascript alerts to determine which HTML elements I needed to manipulate, e.g, 
**javascript: alert(document.forms[3].elements[8].value)** 
would return the value "Save".
I would then have AHK click that element to Save the opportunity. Now I get error messages in Autohotkey and all javascript alerts(Forms 0-3, Elements 1-20) return "Unable to download . Unspecified error".

I have a very beginner level understanding of HTML, so I'm not sure what this means. Could Salesforce have protected the HTML elements from being manipulated?

Comment: Could you add the code you have and the URL to the page you're trying to manipulate? I doubt the HTML elements are protected, but certainly the document structure of the page could be changed to the point where you need to change your AHK code too.

Comment: You Can also try the tool iWB2 learner from here http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1386

Comment: I notice this questions is still unanswered after nearly 4 years. Is an answer still needed, or can it be closed off?

Comment: It can be closed.